# Validity of results recorded in electronic vs bound vs unbound notebooks?

Tags: research-process, note-taking

How do we distinguish between the validity of electronic, recorded bound, and recorded unbound notebooks for gauging whether research results are publishable?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify the connection between "lab notebook" and "research results are publishable"? In particular, use of lab notebooks is *highly* field specific, so please indicate your field in the post?

Comment: Yes, this question makes no sense to me (although I'm admittedly not in a relevant field, so my lack of understanding is probably partly me and partly how the question is written).  Are there really fields where publishability could depend on whether you used an electronic or paper lab notebook, with everything else remaining the same?  That sounds bizarre.

Comment: @Anonymous For *patentability*, records in bound lab notebooks can serve as evidence of being first to invent (See [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inventor%27s_notebook)). I've never heard of anything like this for publishability, though.

Comment: @ff524 although this has recently changed and the only thing relevant nowadays (in the USA) is the date at which the patent application was filed. See: http://techtransfer.jhu.edu/faculty/patents/aia/aia_5changes.html#First-Invent

Answer (score 3):

Where I have been involved with publications and lab notebooks, in biology, this question has never arisen.  Electronic, bound, unbound---I don't usually have any idea what my experimental collaborators are using, and it's not considered relevant.  They are responsible for the integrity of their data, and no journal has ever done any sort of "lab notebook check" on us before publication.  The only place where I can even imagine this would become relevant would be in attempting to resolve an accusation of academic dishonesty.